# Why my buttons are reacting slowly when I use "hidden"?

Tags: javascript, button, hidden

My buttons react to be "hidden" very slowly when I click them. The problem is that user have time to click it more times. What can I do for have "hidden" faster?

Here you have the webpage: http://coatbridgeonline.net/testing/tests/game/index.php

The webpage uses cookies (you can save or delete them by a button inside it).

EDIT:

when you clic food's "+1" appear a new button called farmer.

EDIT:

```
function farmer(){
    document.getElementById("BFarmer").style.visibility="hidden";
    refreshfood();
}


function refreshfood(){
    if (food>=foodprice){
    document.getElementById("BFarmer").style.visibility="visible";
}}

<body onload="farmer(); refreshfood()" style="padding-left: 3%">

<div style="height:40px">           
<button id="BFarmer" onclick="refreshfood(); farmer()" style="visibility:hidden">Farmer</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: Which button is supposed to be hidden?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and explain what you want. Instead of providing link you can put some code.

Comment: ow sorry, whe you clic food's "+1" appear a new button called farmer.

Comment: So put the code, at least the click handler on the farmer button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not hiding your button on click, you are using setTimeout(granjero, 1000);

The if is only called every seconds, so it will only hide if the granjero called.

Comment: the setTimeout is for add food automaticly without clicking, but its not the problem. The question is that the button run ok, but very slowly.

Comment: If you check the source the farmer button has this attirbute: onclick="recargarfood(); restafoodmejoragranjero(); contadorgranjero();"
But none of these handle the visiblity of the button, only the 'granjero' function which is only called every second.

Comment: OK! thank you! I change the code to another function and its running ok now.